# Python : obtain a value by comparing different data frames columns

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I need an help cause I'm trying to obtain a value by comparing different dataframes columns.

First of all, I've tried to use "for loop" to reach the goal, but I have milion of rows, so it takes a lot of time.
Now, I would like to use numpy.where, in this way:

I have 2 data frames:
- df1 where each rows are different to the others (the column ID is the unique primary Key) --> df1['ID', 'status', 'boolean']
- df2 contains few rows, and each rows are different to the others --> 
  df2['code', 'segment', 'value']

Now, I need to create a new column for dataframe1 called 'weight'.

I tried to create the column 'weight' in this way:

```
df1['weight'] = numpy.where(df1['boolean'] == 1, df2[ (df2['code']==df1['ID']) & (df2['segment']==df1['status'])] ['value'], 0)
```

Columns 'code'+'segment' is a unique key, so it returns one and only one value.

The program execution show this error:
"ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Can anyone help me to understand it?

Thank you.

Comment: One moment, i'm trying to give you some examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a left [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Something like this might work. Without sample data I can't check this in detail

```
df_merged = df1.join(df2.set_index(['code', 'segment']), how='left', on=['ID', 'status'])
df1['weight'] = df_merged['value'].re_index(df1.index).fillna(0)
```

The `set_index()` is needed for

> ```
> on : column name, tuple/list of column names, or array-like
> ```
>
> Column(s) in the caller to join on the index in other, otherwise joins index-on-index. If multiples columns given, the passed DataFrame must have a MultiIndex. Can pass an array as the join key if not already contained in the calling DataFrame. Like an Excel VLOOKUP operation